# How to enable cache for bitmap using SimpleImageLoadingListener in Universal Image Loader android

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, android-widget

Hi I have used below code to load image on widget listview item.

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> flags = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


 flags.put(position, false);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                            .build();
                    imageLoader.loadImage(item.mTooteet.getThumbUrl1() + "&userToken=" + userPreference.getUserToken(), options,
                            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingStarted  "+position);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingFailed  "+position);
                                    flags.put(position, true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingCancelled  "+position);
                                    flags.put(position, true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap bitmap) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingComplete  "+position);
                                    mBitmap = bitmap;
                                    flags.put(position, true);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });

            while (!flags.get(position)) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            flags.put(position, false);
            if (mBitmap != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingComplete mBitmap not null "+position);
                remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.feed_image, mBitmap);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"onLoadingComplete mBitmap null "+position);
                remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.feed_image, R.drawable.app_icon);
            }
            mBitmap = null;
```

And in my application file i have used the below code,

```
 // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration uilConfig = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(uilConfig);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
```

But this code will download image from url everytime. I do not want to reload it every time when scrolling my app widget list view. It should be maintained in cache after downloaded first time. Could you please suggest me any idea to do this?

Comment: This is not a solution to your question but a suggestion why can't u use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Its better in my case. I hope to u also?

Comment: @Raghavendra Hi i'm using widget where we can set image on image view like this  remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.feed_image, mBitmap);  where R.id.feed_image is my image view id. I'm getting trouble to use the glide library in widget. Do you know how to use glide in widget like this?

Answer (score 0):

From your code you are creating DisplayImageOptions everytime. I think this is the reason make DisplayImageOptions  for one time(Outside your Runnable objet)
Use like this:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                        .build()
```

Then inside runnable to your other code

```
   handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 imageLoader.loadImage(..........)///same code you written

}
```

});

Please let me know the result.

Comment: I have tried like you said. But its again downloading.

Comment: Universal Image loader first check in your cache with the imgUrl that any cache for this imgUrl is exist or not. If found then load it from cache otherwise download it from server  and cached it. Please  check How much time it takes to show the image in imageView after every load. If time varies from first load to next load than image should be loaded from cache.

Comment: @ MdFazlaRabbiOpu It takes few seconds. Some times it takes more than one mintue.

Comment: @Sangeetha I mean check the same image view time for the first and second load. Seethe time difference.

Comment: It takes 2 secs for first load and 4 seconds for second load, Since i move to the end of the list which contains 50 items. And at times it takes more than this time for first load itself, while scrolling down.